# Accessing struct content, when the type and its content varies between different DLL's

Tags: c++, dll

I have these project in which I need to interface several code-generated dll's (from MATLAB if you're wondering). The dll's are fundamentally similar, let's say that the two functions and the two structs below are the ones that are of interest.

```
function1_ptr  = (void(*)(void)) GetProcAddress(libraryHandle, "NAME_function1");
function2_ptr  = (void(*)(void)) GetProcAddress(libraryHandle, "NAME_function1");
struct1_ptr    = (STRUCT1_TYPE*) GetProcAddress(libraryHandle, "NAME_var1");
struct2_ptr    = (STRUCT2_TYPE*) GetProcAddress(libraryHandle, "NAME_var2");
```

Between the dll's they only vary by the name prefix (*NAME*), the type of the structs (*STRUCTX_TYPE*) and the content of the functions.

The requirements of the code loading these dll's is that it should be able to run the functions (no problem) and be able to get and set the member variables of the two structs (problem!!)
*(The members can be made constant if them variying produces a problem)*

And my question is this:
**What would be the simplest way of interfacing such a collection of dll's given these (very loose) requirements?**
(If the description isn't complete, please post a comment and I'll edit my post)

Below follows my thoughts on a solution that I'm not happy with...

---

My current code is something like this:

```
class Interface
{
    virtual void function1(void) = 0;
    virtual void function2(void) = 0;
    virtual void function3(void) = 0;

    virtual void setInput(STRUCT_MEMBERS_ENUM input, double value) = 0;
virtual double getOutput(STRUCT_MEMBERS_ENUM output) const = 0;
};

template <typename STRUCT1_TYPE, typename STRUCT2_TYPE>
class Model : public Interface 
{
    ...
};
```

The drawbacks of this is that if I want to use a new dll file I need to include a new header file, create a new instance of Model with the relevant struct types and define a new enum with the members of the structs... Because of this, the *dynamic* in dll is sort of lost.

Now I know that C++ doesn't have reflection, but I was hoping for a tip to at least be able to simplify the process of utilizing the content of the dll's i have.

---

I hope a have explained the problem clearly, I will be very thankful for any answer or direction to an answer!

Comment: Every problem is solved by an extra level of indirection.  Create *one* interface, make *two* implementations for them.  And a class factory that instantiates the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you will need the header files for the dll's you want to access. There's no generic way of knowing the structure or contents of a variable. Even with the header files you may be bitten by implementation defined differences between compiler implementations or even just what compiler switches was active when compiling the DLL.

In short: **There's no safe way of doing what you want.**

If the DLL meant for you to access the members of a private variable, it should provide you with accessor functions to get and set the various values.

Comment: Quick question of thought I had...
Could `GetProcAddress(libraryHandle , "structName.member")` possibly work?

Comment: @Stonegoat, that's highly unlikely. Not sure what you can find in the windows DLL's symbol table, though. Should be quick to try.